# Symfony: associating a stylesheet to a template of a plugin

Tags: symfony1

i have this line below in frontend/config/view.yml:

stylesheets:    [main.css]

The rules of that file are applied to the templates of the modules of frontend, but no to the templates of sfDoctrineGuardPlugin.

Even if i write  at the beginning of the template it doesn't work..

What should i do?

Javi

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your sfDoctrineGuardPlugin has a custom "sfGuardAuth" module in your front-end app. The stylesheet will then apply. Works for me without problems.

See "Customize sfGuardAuth module templates" here: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Comment: I did that, and I add to /opt/lampp/htdocs/rs/apps/frontend/modules/sfGuardAuth/config/view.yml this: signinSuccess: has_layout: false stylesheets: [main.css] But it doesn't work..